# Create a grammar for the language L with a^n b^(n/2), where n % 2 = 0

Tags: formal-languages

A grammar for the language L should be designed. $$ L=\left\{ { a }^{ n }{ b }^{ \frac { n }{ 2 }  }|n\in N,\quad n\quad mod\quad 2\quad =\quad 0 \right\} $$  The special part of this language is the modulo operator (n % 2 = 0). Personally, I had a first idea for the grammar, but I can not reconcile it with the modulo operator.

My idea can be formalized something like this:
Set $$ n = 2m $$ then 
$$ {a} ^ {n} {b} ^{ \frac { n }{ 2 }  } = a ^ {2m} {b} ^ {m} $$
From this I derived the production rule:
$$ S --> aaSb | \ E $$
Where E is the empty word. I am not sure if this is correct. What is your opinion about this? I hope my question is clear so far :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is perfect.

Note that $n\in\Bbb N,\ n\,\mathrm{mod}\, 2=0$ means nothing else but that $n$ is a nonnegative even number, so that writing $n=2m$ for some $m\in\Bbb N$ is correct. 
And indeed, the original set of words could also be replaced by
$$L=\{a^{2m}b^m\mid m\in\Bbb N\}$$

Comment: Thaks for your answer this helps me very well! And thanks for the upvote too!